# Date is not inserting in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

i am trying to insert current Time in oracleDB but i am getting some error.

```
"[Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string] errorNum: 1830, offset: 137"
```

current time

```
     var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleString();
```

value of timestamp is 12/21/2018, 2:56:13 PM

i want insert time in this format 04-12-18 03:49:37.000000000 PM

my insert query:

```
     var insertQuery = `insert into ` + global.get('appconfig').oracledbschema + `.` + global.get('appconfig').tableJOBSUMMARY + ` (JOBID,JOBSTARTTIME,LASTUPDATED,RECORDSPROCESSED,JOBTYPE) VALUES 
('` + currentJobID + `', TO_TIMESTAMP('` + timestamp + `', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'','','`+jobtype +`')
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i am using node-red.

Comment: Please share the date format picture and the input string. It appears one is shorter than the other.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson this is my  date format DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FF.

Comment: The error message refers to two things, a *date format picture* and an *input string*. It's important to be clear what those both are.

Comment: Do **not** concatenate user input like that. Use a prepared statement (or whatever the equivalent in your programming language is) that uses placeholders and where you pass the values separately as Objects of the correct type, not as strings

Comment: Does node-red support bind variables for native Oracle datatypes? It would be cleaner to bind a `timestamp` variable than to construct a conversion using concatenated literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: rereading the question, it's not clear what the exact input and conversion format mask are. If I attempt

```
to_timestamp('12/21/2018, 2:56:13 PM', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

I get

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

because there is no month 21.

If I try to use the same format with `'04-12-18 03:49:37.000000000 PM'` (from *"I want insert time in this format"*) I get your `ORA-01830` error.

```
to_timestamp('04-12-18 03:49:37.000000000 PM', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

If this is what you are using, then the error is pointing out that the format mask is too short for the string you are trying to convert. To handle the 9 trailing digits and the AM/PM indicator you will need `'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS.FF9 PM'` (you can use either `AM` or `PM` in the format mask).

Note that if the strings include AM/PM, you can't use `HH24` as in your example.

In case it isn't clear, [`to_timestamp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_TIMESTAMP.html) takes a string such as `'12/21/2018, 2:56:13 PM'` and constructs an Oracle `timestamp`, which is a native datatype like `number`, `varchar2` or `date`. It is stored in an internal binary format and only presented in a human-readable format when required for display purposes. If *"I want to insert time in this format"* means you want to associate a specific display format with a particular timestamp variable, then that isn't possible.

Also, the whole conversion could be avoided if the framework allows you to bind a `timestamp` (or `date`) variable, instead of constructing SQL to do the job on the database using concatenated literals.